# Downloading zip with yeoman generator

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm creating my first Yeoman Generator. I want to download an external zip containing a CMS and unzip it in the root. According to [this thread](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/issues/321) this should be possible. Has this not been implemented yet? What do i need to copy over to my generator if not?

I have run generator generator and got my basic generator up. This is my code so far.

```
Generator.prototype.getVersion = function getVersion() {
  var cb   = this.async()
    , self = this

  this.log.writeln('Downloading Umbraco version 6.1.6')
  this.download('http://our.umbraco.org/ReleaseDownload?id=92348', '.');
}
```

This generates an error telling me that it "cannot find module 'download'". What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Hi. Would you mind accepting my answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I did a little investigation for you.

[There are two methods to download something with yeoman...](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/master/lib/actions/fetch.js)

```
/**
 * Download a string or an array of files to a given destination.
 *
 * @param {String|Array} url
 * @param {String} destination
 * @param {Function} cb
 */

this.fetch(url, destination, cb)

/**
 * Fetch a string or an array of archives and extract it/them to a given
 * destination.
 *
 * @param {String|Array} archive
 * @param {String} destination
 * @param {Function} cb
 */

this.extract(archive, destination, cb)
```

The callback will pass an error if something went wrong.

[There's also a method to download packages from Github.](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/master/lib/actions/remote.js#L13)

```
/**
 * Remotely fetch a package from github (or an archive), store this into a _cache
 * folder, and provide a "remote" object as a facade API to ourself (part of
 * generator API, copy, template, directory). It's possible to remove local cache,
 * and force a new remote fetch of the package.
 *
 * ### Examples:
 *
 *     this.remote('user', 'repo', function(err, remote) {
 *       remote.copy('.', 'vendors/user-repo');
 *     });
 *
 *     this.remote('user', 'repo', 'branch', function(err, remote) {
 *       remote.copy('.', 'vendors/user-repo');
 *     });
 *
 *     this.remote('http://foo.com/bar.zip', function(err, remote) {
 *       remote.copy('.', 'vendors/user-repo');
 *     });
 *
 * When fetching from Github
 * @param {String} username
 * @param {String} repo
 * @param {String} branch
 * @param {Function} cb
 * @param {Boolean} refresh
 *
 * @also
 * When fetching an archive
 * @param {String} url
 * @param {Function} cb
 * @param {Boolean} refresh
 */
```

Comment: Help required!!

What does `repo` and `vendors/user-repo` signify? Is `repo` the entire `URL` path to the actual `repository`?

Comment: @Daggerhunt: remote.copy's arguments are 'source' and 'destination' paths (local), so supposedly you just change the destination to where you want the files to end up. 'repo' should just be the repository name, which is used to construct the url: url = 'https://github.com/' + [username, repo, 'archive', branch].join('/') + '.tar.gz';'